# How to programmatically determine the scale of the quotient from division with two strings?

Tags: c++, math

When we do a division, it should give out `a / b = m...n`, where `m` is the quotient. I have been written a program in C++ to perform arithmetics on strings, without converting any of them to integers. However, the division part always fails to work, as the result scale is always incorrect.

I have tried the following code:

```cpp
long long determineResultScale(const std::string& _number, const std::string& _divisor)
{
    std::string number = _number, divisor = _divisor;
    long long numberScale = determineScale(number);
    const long long divisorScale = determineScale(divisor), diffScale = std::abs(numberScale - divisorScale);

    // Step 1: Make divisor the same scale as number
    // Method: If divisorScale > numberScale -> Scale up number.
    //         If numberScale > divisorScale -> Scale up divisor.
    // Eg.   : 1. 500, 20 => 20 -> 200 (diffScale = 1 -> 20 * 10^1 = 200)
    //         2. 50, 500 => 50 -> 500 (diffScale = 1 -> 50 * 10^1 = 500)
    auto scaleFactor = power("10", std::to_string(diffScale), 0);
    if (divisorScale > numberScale)
    {
        number = multiply(number, scaleFactor, 0);
        if (numberScale > 0)
            numberScale = -numberScale;
    }
    else if (numberScale > divisorScale)
        divisor = multiply(divisor, scaleFactor, 0);
    // Special cases - Same scale.
    else if (numberScale == divisorScale and compare(_number, _divisor, 0) == "0")
        return -1;
    else if (numberScale == divisorScale and compare(_number, _divisor, 0) != "0")
        return 0;

    // Step 2: Squeeze!
    // Method: If number >= divisor -> return numberScale.
    //         Else                 -> return numberScale - 1.
    if (compare(number, divisor, 0) != "0")
        return numberScale;
    if (numberScale < 0)
        return numberScale + 1;
    return numberScale - 1;
}
```

Which attempts to implement a method from [this page](https://worldmentalcalculation.com/how-to-divide-by-long-numbers-in-mental-math/). The `determineScale`, `power`, `compare`, and `multiply` are all implemented correctly and never goes wrong.

Despite working for a few combinations, this function still fails for some cases such as `120321` and `22`. The result should be `5469.13636...`, which has a scale of 3 instead of 4 determined by my method. What is actually going wrong with this?

Comment: Since your `determineScale` is implemented correctly and never goes wrong, and is returning `3`, then I assume that the it's returning 3 instead of 4 because 3 is the correct answer.

Comment: What is "scale" here, though? Are we talking about the power of 10 when expressing the result as "some constant less than 10 times 10 to the power of (scale)"? Because if so, calculate 10^3 and 10^4 on your calculator and have a look at what those numbers are.

Comment: Re "perform arithmetics on strings" In that case, why is there a need to determine "scale"? String-based arithmetic was one of my first projects after I learned how to program (in BASIC, early 1980s) and the division was simply an implementation of decimal long-hand division as taught in elementary school.